# JavaFX 2 Show Tab with code

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I want to show a tab with pressing to a button. I tried

```
SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.select(tab);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: how do you determine `tab` in above example?

Comment: @DenizUğur. It should be working. Are you sure the button action is fired and handled properly? Additionally post your fxml structure of tabpane with its tabs involved in.